# Изменение фона (background-image) блока div на нажатую картинку

Tags: html, изображения, css

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на картинки фоны блока (div) менялись на нажатую картинку?

Вот схема:

[image]

Посоветуйте пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее!!

Answer (score 1):

Если честно - то со "схемы" я ничего не понял, но позволил себе догадаться.

Есть картинки на странице, и при нажатии на эту картинку вы хотите что бы менялся бекгроунд у заданного дива ?

как то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/9P26b/) ?

Comment: есть блоки разные, div_1,div_2,div_3,div_4;
и при нажатия на картинку уменьшенную то в определенном блоке будет фон этой же картинкой. там на отдельном блоке указано "Картинки", там есть несколько картинок которые будут отображаться на фоне блока?

Comment: гуглите галереи jquery.

Comment: нет, галерея думаю не пойдет, надо на каждом блоке разные картинки появились

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что и я правильно понял, но если нужно чтобы по нажатию на картинку в определенном блоке устанавливался фон с этой картинкой, достаточно сделать так:

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="3.jpg" />
    <img src="4.jpg" />
    <img src="5.jpg" />
    <img src="6.jpg" />
    <img src="7.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="blocks">
    <div id="div_1"></div>
    <div id="div_2"></div>
    <div id="div_3"></div>
    <div id="div_4"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".images img").click(function(){
            $("#div_1").css("background", "url('" + $(this).attr("src") + "') 0 0 no-repeat");
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Он хочет сказать, что есть блок сверху расположена панель картинок. Кликаешь на картинки и весь фон данного дива заменяется на эту картинку. 
Думаю тут без скрипта не обойтись. Помочь ничем увы не могу знаю только html+css.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы при клике на определённую картинку изменялся один блок, то:

HTML:

```
<div id="div_1"></div>//Блоки
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
<div id="div_4"></div>
<div class="images">//Контейнер с картинками
<img src="source" class="forDiv_1">//Картинки с метками, для первого блока - forDiv_1 и т.д. Можем копипастить столько, столько надо.
<img src="source" class="forDiv_2">
<img src="source" class="forDiv_3">
<img src="source" class="forDiv_4">
</div>
```

Вот JQuery:

```
    $(".images > img").click(function(){//Добираемся до наших картинок в контейнере
        if($(this).attr("class") === "forDiv_1")//Проверяем, если кликнули на картинку, которая меняет первый блок
            $("#div_1").css("background", "url("+$(this).attr("src")+") 0 0 no-repeat");//меняем его
        if($(this).attr("class") === "forDiv_2")//Повторяем для каждого блока
            $("#div_2").css("background", "url("+$(this).attr("src")+") 0 0 no-repeat");
        if($(this).attr("class") === "forDiv_3")
            $("#div_3").css("background", "url("+$(this).attr("src")+") 0 0 no-repeat");
        if($(this).attr("class") === "forDiv_4")
            $("#div_4").css("background", "url("+$(this).attr("src")+") 0 0 no-repeat");
});
```